# Download manager Process.media Stopped

Tags: android

I am trying to download an audio file using Download manager, But When I am trying to download multiple files I am getting a popup like perocess.media stopped and is appearing quiet often

```
     // DownloadFile AsyncTask
          public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... Url) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(VIDURL);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // Detect the file lenghth
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            /* ......Download Manager...... */

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(VIDURL);

            // Download Manager Request
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Utilities.LocalStoragePath(getApplicationContext()), extractLastWord(VIDURL));

            long ID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            db_obj.DetailsInsertion(extractLastWord(VIDURL), ID + "");
               callNewThread();
            /* ......Download Manager...... */

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Error Log
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is the file being downloaded?

Comment: yes it is... but after the pop up its getting cancelled

Comment: Try this, Settings > Application > All > Download Manager. > Clear Data/Cache.

Comment: But its happening frequently whwn ever I am tryng to download a file

Comment: I don't think its related to your code.